# How to add SQL data into variable?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, variables

How can I add the SQL data into a variable in C#? Thanks for your help.

```
 string user = textBox1.Text;
    string password = textBox2.Text;
    con = new SqlConnection("...");//actually, there is a connection string but because of security, I'm not sharing it with you.
    com = new SqlCommand();
    con.Open();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandText = "Select*From login where username='" + textBox1.Text +
        "'And sifre='" + textBox2.Text + "'";
    dr = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
      
    }
```

It is my login code it will open a new form but first I should find the username data of it and put it into a variable.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Have you already retrieve data from SQL to your C# ? 
You need to be more explicit so we can help you.

Comment: Wait a min. Let i share my code.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0). It has an example. And, in Visual Studio, if you highlight a symbol and press F1, you'll usually get a useful help page.

Comment: You have a [sql injection vulnerability](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) because you concatenate user input into a SQL command instead of using parameters.

Comment: Note for commenters on SQLInj and plaintext passwords; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72098124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pattern to follow, place your data operations in a separate class and call in your form. Here `Login` class could be whatever you want to call it with  required properties.

```
public class Login
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    . . .
}
```

Mocked data class, here since `select *` is used rather than specifying only required columns I assume the first column is the primary key which it may or may not be so adjust as needed and add other columns/properties to the `Login` class instance.

```
public class DataOperations
{
    // caller validates parameters have values
    public static Login DoSomething(string userName, string sifre)
    {
        Login login = new Login();

        var selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username= @userName AND sifre = @sifre";

        using (var cn = new SqlConnection("TODO"))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@sifre", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sifre;

                cn.Open();

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (!reader.HasRows) return login;
                reader.Read();
                login.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }

        return login;
    }
}
```

Call the method above in your form

```
Login login = DataOperations.DoSomething("TODO", "TODO");
```

Comment: Consider showing them Dapper; life's too short to spend days of it writing `cmd.Parameters.Add` ... and it has a much lower barrier to entry than e.g. EF :D

Comment: Also, if `sifre` is the password, a quick "how to salt and hash, and store the hased password" would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Karen's code, using Dapper (right click the project, choose Manage Nuget Packages, click Browse, type Dapper):

```
public static Login DoSomething(string userName, string sifre)
{
    using var c = new SqlConnection("conn str here");
    var id = c.ExecuteScalar<int?>(
        "SELECT id FROM login WHERE username= @u AND sifre = @s", 
        new{ u = textBox1.Text, s = textBox2.Text }
    );

    return new Login() { Id = id ?? 0 };
}
```